# Adding an ad service to Admob mediation

Tags: react-native, admob, ironsource

I am using Admob in my React Native mobile app. My application has risen very quickly and my ad revenues have increased. Today I received a notification saying "Ad serving is limited". That's why I don't want to work with google anymore. I just learned about the meditation service today. I need help as I don't fully understand the situation. I have a few questions regarding the following topic. I would be very grateful if you could answer even one of these.

1- If I add ironSource to meditation even though my Admob application bans ads, can I show ironSource ads with AdMob SDK without a new update to the application? Also, can I set it to show only IronSource ads without showing any Admob ads?

2- I wanted to add ironSource to Admob meditation. I couldn't see the IronSource in the Bidding tab in the image below. I added it to Waterfall. What's the difference between these two? Why is there no IronSource in the Bidding tab?

[image]

3- The last setting I made is as follows. I am currently awaiting approval from IronSource. What exactly does the following 0.01 USD mean? If the revenue of the ad to be shown is less than $0.01, will it not show this ad?

[image]